# Redux Framework slides field - wp_editor instead of textfield

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, redux-framework

I'm trying to customize slides default field ([slides field - Redux framework](http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/slides/)) in order to include wp editor instead of textarea (description area)

original file is here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/master/ReduxCore/inc/fields/slides/field_slides.php

So far I have changed this part of the code

```
if ( $this->field[ 'show' ][ 'description' ] ) {
$placeholder = ( isset ( $this->field[ 'placeholder' ][ 'description' ] ) ) ? esc_attr ($this->field[ 'placeholder' ][ 'description' ] ) : __ ( 'Description', 'redux-framework' );
echo '<li><textarea name="' . $this->field[ 'name' ] . '[' . $x . '][description]' .   $this->field['name_suffix'] . '" id="' . $this->field[ 'id' ] . '-description_' . $x . '" placeholder="' . $placeholder . '" class="large-text" rows="6">' . esc_attr ( $slide[ 'description' ] ) . '</textarea></li>';
}
```

to this:

```
if ( $this->field[ 'show' ][ 'description' ] ) {
$placeholder = ( isset ( $this->field[ 'placeholder' ][ 'description' ] ) ) ? esc_attr ( $this->field[ 'placeholder' ][ 'description' ] ) : __ ( 'Description', 'redux-framework' );
$editor_id =  $this->field[ 'id' ] . '-description_' . $x;

echo '<li> '.wp_editor( $content, $editor_id ,array("textarea_name" => ''.$this->field[ 'name' ] . '[' . $x . '][description]' . $this->field['name_suffix'].'' ));'</li>';
}
```

so, I'm getting wp_editors inside slides, but the problem is, I can not save any content,
BTW each dynamically generated editor text field has unique name and id, like in the original code.

**UPDATE**

just notice that editor doesn't keep the content after page refresh, but stores the data on the first submit.

Answer (score 4):

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

wp_editor takes three parameters.  You have four showing in your code.  I'm surprised this did not kick back an error or warning.

So, change this

```
echo '<li> '.wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, '',array("textarea_name" => ''.$this->field[ 'name' ] . '[' . $x . '][description]' . $this->field['name_suffix'].'' ));'</li>';
```

}

to this

```
echo '<li> '.wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, array("textarea_name" => ''.$this->field[ 'name' ] . '[' . $x . '][description]' . $this->field['name_suffix'].'' ));'</li>';
```

}